# Can anybody idtentify what this drain vent is for?

Tags: plumbing, vent, drain-waste-vent

I am trying to identify the reason for a drain vent in an area of my house with no other plumbing. The house only has 1 bathroom and a kitchen sink. The kitchen sink drains into a grease trap and has a 1.5" vent. The bathroom has a separate drain that meet somewhere in the backyard and has a 2" vent. Then there is a third vent that enters the foundation in an area where there is no other plumbing. Here is a photo of the vent and where it is located in the house:
[image]
[image]

I have spent the past few days ripping all the rotten drywall out of the house and can say with confidence that nobody ever updated the plumbing in this house with any kind of long term view. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Given the "cast iron transitions to plastic" (or at least "new and older piping connect") it would appear that the toilet was moved, and the vent was preserved.

Comment: So given both these answers it sounds like there must have been some other plumbing here at some point. IE, this isn't some second vent from the grease trap. If that is the case, I think I can just cap this vent seeing as no drain requires it as an air source.

Answer (score 0):

With the area being at the back of the house I would think it could be a vent for a washing machine and or a mud sink.